# The meaning of Idiom like "Killed something"

Tags: slang

Here's my question.

When we say "He really killed the fried chicken",

Does it mean...

> 1) He really loves fried chicken and scarf down, while having it.

or

> 2) He's really good at making the dish

Does the meaning depend on the situation/context?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I think your last part explains it best. The word _killed_ is being used as figurative slang, and it could refer to his voracious appetite, or to his culinary skills. (As a side note, I noticed that you've accepted an answer here rather quickly – perhaps [too quickly](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307)).

Comment: In the sense of eating the chicken, the important thing is not how much he liked it, nor how quickly he ate it, but that he ate ALL of it. Or, to use your term, he _scarfed it ALL down_.  Sometimes this is intensified by saying **killed it off**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you would want to include an article:

> **He really killed *the* fried chicken**.

Second, you are correct – either meaning is possible, and more context would help us determine which meaning is intended. Consider:

> He killed a whole bucket of Kentucky Fried Chicken! Amazing!

I'd assume that meant [eating the whole thing](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kill&defid=267757) (probably in one sitting). However:

> He killed that fried chicken last night. It was delicious!

I'd assume that referred to [how well the chicken was prepared](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kill&defid=5855050).

Third, you should realize this is a very informal use of the verb *kill*, and that word has other slang meanings as well. In addition to the two meanings you list here, it can also mean [to ruin](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kill&defid=90570):

> He killed that fried chicken last night. We had to go out to eat instead.

Fourth, absent any further context, the original sentence could mean that he literally butchered the chickens:

> He really killed the fried chicken!
>   *What, do you mean he cooked it well?*
>   No, I mean he really killed it! Some friend of his has a chicken farm about 30 miles from town – we went there last weekend and killed three birds.

Comment: Orthographically, 'killed' should be 'ruined'. That way, in cooking, if someone 'kills' the dish, she should be ruining it completely. That's what came **first** in my mind till I referred the UD.

Comment: @Maulik - Except with slang, words often can become autoantonyms, which is why _bad_ can mean _good_, and _killed_ can mean _aced_. That's why we need more context.

Comment: I was ready to +1 until you got to the butchering.  You don't butcher the *prepared* dish.  He butchered the Beef Wellington?  *Butcher* there could only be taken figuratively, not literally.

Comment: @TRomano - No, but you can butcher the bird that was eventually fried. I have a friend who raises turkeys. Around the holidays a few years ago, my daughters and I visited his farm, and helped him butcher some birds. That year, I could have easily said, "Nancy killed the Thanksgiving turkey" and nothing would have been grammatically (or factually) wrong with that sentence.

Comment: @J.R. But Nancy didn't butcher (kill) the *deep-fried* or kill the *oven-roasted* turkey. We' d find another way to say that Nancy did the butchering of the animal; we wouldn't refer to the animal as the prepared dish.  "The *Thanksgiving* turkey" is a different animal, as it were.  "He butchered the Christmas goose" is fine. "He butchered the roasted goose" isn't.

Comment: @TRomano - We might have to agree to disagree on this. The Thanksgiving turkey and the turkey Nancy killed were most assuredly _not_ a different animal. In fact, they were very much the same animal – same as same can be. _Somebody_ had to kill that turkey you're eating; usually we don't know who that is, but, on Thanksgiving Day in 2012, Nancy killed the bird – and then we cooked it two days later.

Comment: @J.R.  You cooked the bird two days later, so Nancy couldn't have killed *the cooked bird*; however, Nancy could have killed *the bird you cooked*.  She couldn't have killed *the eaten bird* but she could have killed *the bird you ate*.  It's a language thing, not a turkey thing.

Comment: @TRomano - Well, that's just semantics, I think. I get your point, but I'll stand by my answer. You should try letting your daughter slaughter the Thanksgiving turkey sometime – and see what kind of jokes fly around the table during that feast. :^) Sometimes we native speakers can be a little lax with English rules when the circumstances are unusual and it suits our purposes. If a friend was telling me about their trip to the poultry farm, and said, "Bob killed the fried chicken," I wouldn't correct him and say, "No, Bob killed the chicken that Jim fried." That's a bit pedantic for my tastes.

Answer (score 2):

[*Killing it*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Killing%20It) means that you're doing something really well.

You don't necessarily need the it, but could also simply say this:

> - He really **killed** *the fried chicken*.
> - I totally **killed** *the exam*.

Comment: It is slang, so you will probably not find it in dictionaries other than the urban dictionary. You can Google search for the expression and you will see that it is used in this sense.

Comment: I updated my answer. After some more research I found that it was not entirely correct.

Comment: I don't think you need to include the _it_. [One entry in UD](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kill&defid=267757) says: **kill** _to finish something (mostly food or drink) : Hey can I kill that sandwich?_ [Another](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kill&defid=5855050) says that _kill_ means "to do really well on," as in, _I killed that test today!_ In short, I think your answer was more accurate **before** the modifications prompted by the challenge by @Maulik

Comment: @J.R. the sentence in quote makes it clear. In fact, that's what I expected especailly after looking the UD's example *there*.

Comment: @Maulik - The O.P.'s original sentence could have at least two meanings. Sander's modified sentence eliminates the "scarfing it down" meaning, but that bit about needing to say "killing *it*" instead of "killed" is inaccurate; we could just as easily say: _He killed the fried chicken last night – it was scrumptious._ (I don't know what example you looked at; the UD has more than 50 for the word _kill_.)

Comment: You don't need an *it*. He really killed that fried chicken. Compare the phrase "He really nailed that song" -> "He really sang that song very well."

Answer (score -1):

"He really killed the fried chicken" means he ruined it.

There is a double entendre to saying this. The chicken is already dead in the literal sense, but when you say "killed it" you are also referring to killing (i.e.) destroying the chicken.

As mentioned, "killing it" can have a positive connotation too. It depends how you say it. You would generally say "it" as part of the phrase alá "killing it" or "killed it" rather than saying "killed [name of thing killed]". Otherwise you might not get your point across. People might not realise you're using slang.